# trying to Configur c3p0 pooling in Hibernate using Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-webflow, c3p0

I am Configuring the built-in c3p0 pooling in Hibernate using Spring but its giving me error it does not like any of the C3P0 stuff like:

```
<prop name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="2" />
<prop name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
```

Can someone please tell me why?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!--suppress InjectionValueTypeInspection -->
    <property name="mappingResources" ref="hibernateMappingList" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">net.sf.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="transaction.factory_class">
                net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
                net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>

            <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="2" />
            <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
            <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="600" />
            <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
            <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is my database source information:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${database.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${database.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${database.maxPoolSize}" /> 
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${database.maxIdleTime}" />

        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: What error? Can you post details about the error?

Comment: Spring does not like the "prop name="

Comment: Can you paste your datasource configuration?. Also I see you use <prop name-?> for all your cpo configurations. Did you try something like   <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size"  >2</prop>

Comment: i added the datasource information and if I add <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" >2</prop> I dont get a xml error but C3P0 is not using the values

Answer (score 1):

The XML is wrong. In the following section

```
       <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="2" />
       <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
       <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="600" />
       <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
       <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
       <prop name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
```

replace it using the same format as with the other properties

```
       <prop key="key">value</prop>
```

The `prop` element uses different attributes than the `property` element.

Comment: I did try that and I change the sizes to test and it did not work... I made the min_size to 10 and still got the min from the datassource

Comment: One answer per question :). If you already fixed your original problem, mark this answer as the correct one and ask another question.